# How do I completely uninstall ruby, rails, rvm, gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I am very new to Ruby on Rails. I have installed ruby, rails, gems, and RVM (and possibly some more RoR-associated files) via Mac OS terminal.
When I first installed these softwares, they seemed to work fine, and I could execute command lines like:
rails new 'project'    or    rails server
But then I messed around with git, directory, and some sudo bundle/gem commands a little bit because "bundle install" command wouldn't work. Honestly, I don't know what I have done, but all of these command lines have stopped working now.
They output various error messages, such as:

1) There was an error parsing 'Gemfile': Undefined local variable or method for Gemfile. Bundler cannot continue.

2) bash: /usr/local/bin/rails: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: bad interpreter:   No such file or directory

3) ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
   You don't have write permissions

4) find spec_for exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)

I think there were more errors, but these are all I can remember for now. Obviously, I am getting some intimidating error messages that I don't understand.

So I have come to a conclusion that I should uninstall all Ruby, Rails, Gems, RVM, and Homebrew files. But even this task looks very challenging to me. 
I have tried numerous command lines in an attempt to delete them, but when I type in "rails" on spotlight, I still see lots of rails-associated files. Also, when I type "ruby -v" on terminal, it is still showing the ruby 2.0.0p648 version.

When I type in "which ruby" on terminal, it says "/usr/bin/ruby
When I type in "which rails" on terminal, it says "usr/local/bin/rails

In short, I just want to delete all of these RoR-related files, softwares, and every trace of them, and reinstall them clean. Please please help me. I do not want to give up coding. Is it too late to say that I'm sorry?

```
#This is my .bash_profile

# Enable tab completion
source ~/.profile

# colors!
green="\[\033[0;32m\]"
blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"
purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"
reset="\[\033[0m\]"

# Change command prompt
source ~/git-prompt.sh
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
# '\u' adds the name of the current user to the prompt
# '\$(__git_ps1)' adds git-related stuff
# '\W' adds the name of the current directory
export PS1="$purple\u$green\$(__git_ps1)$blue \W $ $reset"

alias subl="/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
~                                                                               
"~/.bash_profile" 21L, 720C
```

Comment: Can you paste your gemfile contents

Comment: Sure. I typed in "gemfile" on spotlight. It's showing five different folders called "gemfiles" in different directory. I'm assuming they were made when I created new rails projects. Each folder contains different gems. The one in user directory has "alaska", "rubyracer", and "rubyrhino". The one in desktop directory has about seven different versions of "rails_3_0.gemfile", "rails_3_1.gemfile", "rails_3_2.gemfile" and so on.
Another gemfiles folder (under bootstrap-sass) has rails_head.gemfile.
sass_3_3.gemfile, sass_3_4.gemfile, sass_head.gemfile.

Comment: You should not use sudo when you're doing bundle install. It could be permission problem when you want to use the installed gem. My advice is you need to uninstall the gem that is installed with sudo command. Then install it back without using sudo.

Comment: Yeah I realize I shouldn't have done that. Could you explain how I would uninstall all gems and other ruby/rails files, so I can start back from the scratch?

Answer (score 3):

Ruby is installed on OS X by default.  So you don't want to remove that, there are things that might require ruby that has nothing to do with rails or your rails projects, you should ignore it.  (and you should probably not use spotlight for finding dev files, its just confusing as to what is safe and what is not to play with)

Secondly, you'll hardly EVER use sudo for any rails-related work on your mac, so if a tutorial wants you to run that command, don't.

And lastly, its possible it's not as bad as you think. So there's 2 steps. 1 - Fix your rvm environment and 2 - fix your gemfile

***TO RESOLVE***
 --Start be reinstalling RVM

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

Now because it's changed your shell environment (added variables and aliases) and because you've changed some things that are unpredictable... Log out, and log back into your mac.

** Which ruby is in use now? **

```
which ruby
```

If you're system is still showing /usr/bin/ruby then you'll need to edit your shell profiles.  Because I don't know what you might have done, or what shell env you're using I'll just be thorough. Any excess won't hurt.

You'll review (in the editor of your choice) 4 hidden files in your home directory

```
/Users/yourhome/.profile

/Users/yourhome/.bashrc

/Users/yourhome/.zshrc

/Users/yourhome/.bash_profile
```

If you're using bash, then make sure your bash_profile has in it

```
source ~/.profile
```

In the bashrc nad zshrc files make sure the rvm path exists

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

In the .profile file make sure this command exists

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

-- Once you've saved your changes, log out and back in (you shouldn't have have to do this but again, just being thorough).

Once that is done, you should be able to install a ruby -

```
rvm install ruby-2.2.3
```

Now if you say rvm use ruby-2.2.3 and then which ruby, you should see a pointer to your home directory where rvm lives.

---

*** Now to fix the Gemfile ***
You have an encoding problem, which is what caused you the errors that made you see spots in the first place.  If you paste the contents of the file here

(in a terminal in the directory of your rails project)

cat Gemfile

Paste those contents here and it can be fixed.

Comment: First of all, I'd like to thank you so much for trying to help me out.
Ok, I did redownload rvm successfully.
And after that, when I tried which ruby, it still showed /usr/bin/ruby.
So I tried to follow your steps. 
When I typed in "/Users/yourhome/.profile" on terminal, it says 
-bash: /Users/myhome/.profile: Permission denied

Comment: Okay I just typed in vim ~/.hiddenfilenames  on terminal and looked through all four files and they seem fine. Except bash_profile has bunch of long codes. Since the code is too long to paste in the comment section, I have added the .bash_profile code in my original text. Please take a look!

Comment: if your profile says permission denied, then it means as root you've modified the permissions so your regular user doesn't have access to your proper shell environment.  to fix that --- `sudo chmod 644 ~/.profile` -- then make sure you own it, not root ---- `sudo chown yourusername:staff ~/.profile`

Comment: After those two command lines, am I supposed to be able to access by just simply typing "~/.profile" on terminal? I did execute those lines and when I type in "~/.profile" , it still says "-bash: /Users/myusername/.profile: Permission denied". But I am able to access and review the content by executing "vim ~/.profile"

Comment: you never really "access" your .profile, it's not used by you mostly, it's used by the system to define your environment.  Did you change the yourusername part to whatever your actual username is?

Comment: Yes I did. They seem to contain all the information you listed. Idk what's wrong...T.T

Comment: Also, another thing I've noticed is that on terminal, my username appears differently. It shows "username (master*) ~$ ". The (master*) part wasn't there originally. I don't know what I have changed. Possibly I switched some settings while I was messing with Git on terminal. Maybe this is causing problems? Please help! :(((